# How can I create an acronym from a string in MATLAB?

Tags: regex, string, matlab, acronym

Is there an easy way to create an acronym from a string in MATLAB? For example:

```
'Superior Temporal Gyrus' => 'STG'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### If you want to put every capital letter into an abbreviation...

... you could use the function [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/regexpi.html):

```
str = 'Superior Temporal Gyrus';  %# Sample string
abbr = str(regexp(str,'[A-Z]'));  %# Get all capital letters
```

... or you could use the functions [UPPER](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/upper.html) and [ISSPACE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/isspace.html):

```
abbr = str((str == upper(str)) & ~isspace(str));  %# Compare str to its uppercase
                                                  %#   version and keep elements
                                                  %#   that match, ignoring
                                                  %#   whitespace
```

... or you could instead make use of the [ASCII/UNICODE values](http://www.cs.utk.edu/~pham/ascii_table.jpg) for capital letters:

```
abbr = str((str <= 90) & (str >= 65));  %# Get capital letters A (65) to Z (90)
```

### If you want to put every letter that starts a word into an abbreviation...

... you could use the function [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/regexpi.html):

```
abbr = str(regexp(str,'\w+'));  %# Get the starting letter of each word
```

... or you could use the functions [STRTRIM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strtrim.html), [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html), and [ISSPACE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/isspace.html):

```
str = strtrim(str);  %# Trim leading and trailing whitespace first
abbr = str([1 find(isspace(str))+1]);  %# Get the first element of str and every
                                       %#   element following whitespace
```

... or you could modify the above using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/access//helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1) to avoid the call to [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html):

```
str = strtrim(str);  %# Still have to trim whitespace
abbr = str([true isspace(str)]);
```

### If you want to put every *capital* letter that starts a word into an abbreviation...

... you can use the function [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/regexpi.html):

```
abbr = str(regexp(str,'\<[A-Z]\w*'));
```

Comment: @Jonas: Wheeeeee[taptaptap]eeeeee!

Comment: Nice answer to a very vague question

Answer (score 0):

thanks, also this:

```
s1(regexp(s1, '[A-Z]', 'start'))
```

will return abbreviation consisting of capital letters in the string. Note the string has to be in Sentence Case

Comment: The `'start'` option is actually unnecessary, since by default the first argument returned from REGEXP will be the starting indices of matches.