# How to deal with strings in matlab?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

How do I do this in matlab using a function?

```
hidden ('great summer time') %returns 'gst'.
hidden ('no on no east') %returns 'none'.
hidden ('this is an example') %returns 'tiae'.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540139/how-to-create-a-function-that-returns-an-acronym-in-matlab or even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038768/how-can-i-create-an-acronym-from-a-string-in-matlab

Comment: @KassymDorsel - Very nice find. I've marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions, (`regexp` command) to extract the first letters of each word.

```
function out = hidden(str)

    out = str(regexp([' ' str],'(?<=\s+)\S','start')-1);

end
```

Seeing as this is just a one liner with one output you can put it in an anonymous function inline with your script . . .

```
@(str)str(regexp([' ',str],'(?<=\s+)\S','start')-1)

>> hidden('things to do')

ans =

ttd
```

Comment: I think he means to collect the first letter of each word, probably automatic and not typing up everything and then letting an if statement return your exact written code.

Comment: DoH. Ok. I'm getting hammered for the bad question :P

Comment: Edited now I think I have teased out the meaning of the question

Comment: @learnvst - I've offset your downvote.  Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isspace`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isspace.html) to find all spaces and select the first character of the string and all characters following a space:

```
function [s] = hidden(str)

s = str([1, find(isspace(str))+1]);

end
```